# Why do I receive the error, "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def bmi(weight,height):
    """bmi calculates anyones bmi.
    weight=weight in pounds,height=someones height in inches,
    this function returns the person's body mass index"""
    weight_calc=weight*0.45  #converts weight to kilograms
    height_calc=height*0.025  #converts height to meters
    square=height_calc**2
    calc=weight_calc/square #final bmi calculation
    print 'For someone who is',height,'inches tall, and  
    weighs',weight,'pounds, their body mass index is',calc 



def new_bmi():
    """asks someone their height in inches, and weight in pounds.Then
    calcs bmi"""
    tall=raw_input('How tall are you in inches?\n')
    heavy=raw_input('How much do you weigh in pounds?\n')
    print 'You are',tall,'inches tall, and weigh',heavy,'pounds.'
    float(heavy)
    bmi(heavy,tall)



new_bmi()
```

I have to write a program that asks someone their height in inches and their weight in pounds, and then uses that info to calculate their BMI using the bmi function. I keep receiving the error: 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

thanks for any responses, they are much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In `weight_calc=weight*0.45` the variable `weight` is a string from the user input, not an float or an int. You'll have the same problem with the line after it. At some point in your code you need to convert the weight and height to floats if you want decimal values, or int if you only want whole numbers. I suggest making the conversion when you call the bmi function:

```
#bmi(heavy,tall) #this is passing heavy and tall as strings, not numbers
bmi(float(heavy),float(tall)) #<-- use this instead
```

Output:

```
('For someone who is', 60.0, 'inches tall, and weighs', 160.0, 'pounds, their body mass index is', 32.0)
```